# Chaincode instantiate error in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, chaincode

Presently I have these configuration (TLS enabled)

- **Org1 = Has two peers, peer0 and peer1**
- **Org2 = Has two peers, peer0 and peer1**

I have created a channel named : **mychannel**, all four peers have joined in it, and chaincode is installed onto four peers.

The problem is when I tried to do, chaincode instantiate, I am getting the below error

```
Failed to invoke chaincode name:"Iscc", error: container exited with 0
```

I am not having any idea about this error, can anyone please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that chaincode failed during startup.

After building chaincode and running `chaincode instantiate` , fabric will create docker container to start running your chaincode on it, the container name has prefix `dev-peerxxxxxx` so open this container logs by this command `docker logs -f dev-peerxxxx` ( replace xxxxx by actual container name ) and check if there's any errors during startup.

In your case you will got 4 containers, one container for each peer, so check any one of them.

Comment: Thanks Yasser Mas, Issue fixed, there was a problem with the docker network